# Time Derivative of PDE solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Consider the PDE 
$$
\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}(t,x)=\psi''(t,x)+2\psi\psi'(t,x)-\tilde V'(x)~ on~ [0,D/2]\times(0,\infty)\\
\psi(0,t)=0, \psi(D/2,t)=-k, \\\psi(\cdot,0)=\psi_0
$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. $\psi_0$ is - except a finite point set- a stationary solution of the corresponding ODE and in such a way that  $\psi$ remains under $\psi_0$ at all times, there's also a subsolution, which is a smooth stationary solution and satisfies the same boundary conditions.

I'm trying to prove that $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}\leq 0$. My approach:
Differentiating the PDE with respect to $t$ and writing $\eta=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}$
gives
$$
\frac{\eta }{\partial t}=\eta''+2\psi\eta'+2\psi'\eta \\
\psi(0,t)=\psi(D/2,t)=0.
$$
I'm thinking of applying the strong parabolic maximum principle, since it seems straight forward to me that $\eta$ should be non positiv near $t=0$ ( $\psi$ remains under the supersolution $\psi_0$). However, $\psi$ need not be differentiable with respect to $t$ at $t=0$ and I can't exclude any oscillating behaviour of $\eta$. Does anyone know how to proceed or has another idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Would this be of use? $$\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\psi^{'}-\psi^{2}-\tilde{V(x)}\right)$$

Comment: I can't see how, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I will show a way to transform your equation into a simpler form which might allow for a easier analysis of your problem.

Starting with your equation

$$ \frac{d\psi}{dt} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\psi' + \psi^2 - V\right)$$

we define $$\zeta(x,t) \equiv \int_0^x\psi(z,t)dz$$ and by integrating your equation over $x$ (we ignore boundary terms; or redefine $V$ to account for them) we find

$$ \frac{d\zeta}{dt} = \zeta'' + (\zeta')^2-V$$

To simplify it further we define $\beta(x,t) \equiv e^{\zeta(x,t)}$ which gives

$$\frac{d\beta}{dt} = \beta'' - V\beta$$

This is the well known Heat equation (with $V$ describing internal heat generation/loss) or if you like: a Schrodinger equation in imaginary time. Note that the original variable is given by

$$\psi(x,t) = \left(\frac{\beta'(x,t)}{\beta(x,t)}\right)$$

Now since the equation for $\beta$ is separable we can, if needed, solve it using separation of variables: $\beta = X(x) T(t)$. For a zero potential (can also be solved analytically for a linear and quadratic potential) we find

$$ \beta(x,t) = A \cos(\omega x)e^{-\omega^2 t}$$

where the second boundary condition imply that $\tan(\omega D/2) = k/\omega$ whose solutions forms a countable set $\{\omega_i\}_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ and the general solution therefore reads

$$\beta(x,t) = \sum_i A_i \cos(\omega_i x)e^{-\omega^2_i t}$$

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, i've thought of similar techniques. Do you have any idea how this could lead to proving the assertion? I think one can assume that $k=0$ and that the initial data is a supersolution has to be crucial.

Comment: @user128470 From the expression for $\psi$ in terms of $\beta$ it follows that $\dot{\psi} \leq 0$ iff $\beta'''\beta \leq \beta'' \beta'$ or in terms of mixed derivatives: $\dot{\beta}'\beta \leq \dot{\beta} \beta'$. Maybe this is easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The boundary condition $\psi(D/2, -t) = -k$ and under the suggested transformation $\psi(D/2, t) = 0$ seems to be in question.

In the general sense the equation
\begin{align}
\partial_{t} \psi(x,t) = \partial_{x} \left( \partial_{x} \psi(x,t) - \psi^{2}(x,t) - \tilde{V} \right)
\end{align}
is of separable form in the sense $\psi(x,t) = \psi_{0}(x) e^{-|E|t}$. Making this substitution then
\begin{align}
-|E| = \partial_{x} \left( \partial_{x} \psi(x,t) - \psi^{2}(x,t) - \tilde{V} \right)
\end{align}
which leaves a non-linear pde in $\psi_{0}(x)$. Now, 
\begin{align}
\partial_{t} \psi(x,t) = - |E| \psi(x,t) \leq 0
\end{align}
for $\psi(x,t) \geq 0$ over the domain.

Comment: I'm sorry, should be $\psi(D/2,t)=-k$, just corrected it. I'm not an expert in non-linear PDEs so is $E$ the evolution operator of the PDE (do you have a good reference that it exists?)? And I still don't see how the last step follows, in fact, what about the sign of $|E|$ and actually $\psi$ need not be positive (or do I have to subtract the initial data or sth. like that)? And by the way, $\psi_0$ isn't smooth everywhere, so $\psi$ is neither if this identity holds.

Comment: $E$ can be positive or negative. When the absolute value of $E$, namely $|E|$, is used then there is no sign issue because $|E| \geq 0$. Indeed if $\psi_{0} < 0$ then the above suggested statement is invalid.

Comment: Yeah wasn't sure if you meant the absolute value by that. However, how can you verify the identity $\psi=\psi_0(x)e^{-|E|t}$ and wouldn't       $-|E| = \partial_{x} ( \partial_{x} \psi(x,t) - \psi^{2}(x,t) - \tilde{V}) $ already mean that $\psi_t$ is negative in the first place (since the right hand side of the PDE must be positive)? shouldn't it be $-E = \partial_{x} ( \partial_{x} \psi(x,t) - \psi^{2}(x,t) - \tilde{V}) $?

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more precise?
1. How do you know that $\psi=\psi_0e^{-|E|t}$ and 
2. How is $E$ defined? It seems weird to me that you define its absolute value and not the variable itself

Comment: Since the pde is single variable in $t$ it will have an exponential form. This can be seen by making use of separation of variables. The constant, in this case $|E|$, is the separation constant. In this case it is chosen such that the constant can be positive or negative, but the term $- |E|$ is always negative, again from the method of separation of variables.

Comment: Does your solution satisfy the second boundary condition? $\psi(D/2,t) = -k \to \psi_0(D/2) e^{-|E|t} = -k$ only for $|E| = 0$ right?

Comment: And how can it be separable when $V=V(x)$ and we have non-linear term $\psi^2$ ?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't make that much sense to me either, one could subtract the subsolution to get a positive solution (of a modified PDE)vanishing on the boundary, still I don't see how to get it in an appropriate separable form.